# Can't use execute-command --interactive in AWS CLI session manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-session-manager

I'm trying to use the AWS cli + session manager plugin to get into a database container to run some migrations, and I am struggling to get it working. I'm trying to use the following command:

```
aws ecs execute-command --cluster {cluster}  --task {task} --container {container} --interactive 
 --command "/bin/sh"
```

And the error message it gives me is: `aws.exe: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:`
along with a list of possible commands to use.

I've also tried running

```
aws ecs update-service --service {service} --cluster {cluster} --enable-execute-command
```

and it gives me the error `Unknown options: --enable-execute-command`. I've also tried these commands with the region parameter included, but it gives me the same error messages. I've tried this all in a few different terminals - bash, powershell, and wsl.

I'm using AWS CLI version 2.0.27, and session manager plugin version 1.2.279.0. Does anyone know what I should try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS CLI 2.0.27 is 2 years old. You need to update it to get support for new options.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue again, and ended up finding this post that I had made and forgotten about. Your answer was once again quite helpful, and I wanted to add that I had to install awscli using pip instead of apt to get the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html), you need AWS CLI 2.3.6 or later.